# Validating Requests for BundleConfig Routes/URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, bundling-and-minification

Is there a way in ASP.NET to validate Requests' parameters sent in Virtual Paths/Routes created using the BundleConfig ScriptBundle?

Example:

I have a BundleConfig configurations as below:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bjqs").Include(
                "~/Scripts/bjqs-1.3.js"));
```

If a user sends a request like the following:

http://example.com/bundles/bjqs?v=parameter-value_to%be+validated

How do I validate the value passed in the query string v parameter against a regex before the request being handled/processed by ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom [HttpModule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx) to intercept the request. For example:

```
public class MyModule1 : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose() {}

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.AuthorizeRequest += context_AuthorizeRequest;
    }

    void context_AuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = (HttpApplication)sender;

        // Check if the parameter is valid, your logic
        if (ValidateRequest(app.Context.Request))
        {
            // Then do nothing
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise, return unauthorized response
        app.Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        app.Context.Response.End();
    }
}
```